# Cluster histograms using Earth Movers Distance R

Tags: r, histogram, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have data represented as a number of different histograms of a single variable.  I would like to determine which histograms are similar using unsupervised clustering.  I would also like to know the optimal number of clusters to use.

I have read about the Earth Movers Distance metric as a measure of distance between histograms but don't know how to use that in common clustering algorithms (e.g., k means).

**Primary**: What r packages and functions do I use to cluster histograms?

**Secondary**: How do I determine the 'optimal' number of clusters?

Example Dataset 1 (3 uni-modal clusters):

```
v1 <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 10, sd = 1)  # cluster 1 (around 10)
v2 <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 50, sd = 5)  # cluster 2 (around 50)
v3 <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 100, sd = 10) # cluster 3 (around 100)
v4 <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 12, sd = 2)  # cluster 1
v5 <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 45, sd = 6)  # cluster 2
v6 <- rnorm(n=100, mean = 95, sd = 6)  # cluster 3
```

Example Dataset 2 (3 bi-modal clusters):

```
b1  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=9, sd=2) , rnorm(n=100, mean=200, sd=20))   # cluster 1 (around 10 and 200)
b2  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=50, sd=5), rnorm(n=100, mean=100, sd=10))  # cluster 2 (around 50 and 100)
b3  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=99, sd=8), rnorm(n=100, mean=175, sd=17)) # cluster 3 (around 100 and 175)
b4  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=12, sd=2), rnorm(n=100, mean=180, sd=40))  # cluster 1
b5  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=45, sd=6), rnorm(n=100, mean=80, sd=30))  # cluster 2
b6  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=95, sd=6), rnorm(n=100, mean=170, sd=25))  # cluster 3
b7  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=10, sd=1), rnorm(n=100, mean=210, sd=30))   # cluster 1 (around 10 and 200)
b8  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=55, sd=5), rnorm(n=100, mean=90, sd=15))  # cluster 2 (around 50 and 100)
b9  <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=89, sd=9), rnorm(n=100, mean=165, sd=20)) # cluster 3 (around 100 and 175)
b10 <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=8, sd=2), rnorm(n=100, mean=160, sd=30))  # cluster 1
b11 <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=55, sd=6), rnorm(n=100, mean=110, sd=10))  # cluster 2
b12 <- c(rnorm(n=100, mean=105, sd=6), rnorm(n=100, mean=185, sd=21))  # cluster 3
```

Comment: EMD is very expensive, so you need to use lower bounds and indexes to accelerate your clustering. K-means only works for Bregman divergences, and I don't think EMD is one.

Answer (score 2):

Clustering Solution for Example Dataset 1:

```
library(HistDAWass)

# create lists of histogram distributions
lod<-vector("list",6)
lod[[1]] <- data2hist(v1, type = "regular")
lod[[2]] <- data2hist(v2, type = "regular")
lod[[3]] <- data2hist(v3, type = "regular")
lod[[4]] <- data2hist(v4, type = "regular")
lod[[5]] <- data2hist(v5, type = "regular")
lod[[6]] <- data2hist(v6, type = "regular")

# combine separate lists into a matrix of histogram objects
mymat <- new("MatH", nrows=6, ncols=1, ListOfDist=lod, names.rows=c(1:6), names.cols="density")

# calculate clusters pre-specifying number of clusters (k)
WH_kmeans(mymat, k=3)

# the output of this gives the expected 3 clusters
```

Clustering Solution for Example Dataset 2:

```
lod<-vector("list",12)
lod[[1]] <- data2hist(b1, type = "regular")
lod[[2]] <- data2hist(b2, type = "regular")
lod[[3]] <- data2hist(b3, type = "regular")
lod[[4]] <- data2hist(b4, type = "regular")
lod[[5]] <- data2hist(b5, type = "regular")
lod[[6]] <- data2hist(b6, type = "regular")
lod[[7]] <- data2hist(b7, type = "regular")
lod[[8]] <- data2hist(b8, type = "regular")
lod[[9]] <- data2hist(b9, type = "regular")
lod[[10]] <- data2hist(b10, type = "regular")
lod[[11]] <- data2hist(b11, type = "regular")
lod[[12]] <- data2hist(b12, type = "regular")

mymat2 <- new("MatH", nrows=12, ncols=1, ListOfDist=lod, names.rows=c(1:12), names.cols="density")

WH_kmeans(mymat2, k=3)

# the output of this also gives the expected 3 clusters
```

**Determining "Optimal" number of clusters:**

I'm not sure what the best metric would be but this package spits out a `quality` metric in the output.  So, while it is inefficient to compute several solutions and then evaluate them, using this was my initial solution.

Optimal clusters for Example Dataset 1:

```
df = data.frame()
for(i in 2:5) {
  df = rbind(df, data.frame(n_clust = i, quality = WH_kmeans(mymat, k=i)$quality))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x=n_clust, y=quality)) + geom_point(size=4) + geom_line()
```

[image: Example 1 Optimality plot]

The plot shows a clear increase in "quality" between 2 clusters and 3 clusters and little improvement above 3 clusters.  So, I choose 3 as "optimal". This makes sense since I created the raw data example specifically to have 3 clusters.

For example 2:

```
df2 = data.frame()
for(i in 2:11) {
  df2 = rbind(df2, data.frame(n_clust = i, quality = WH_kmeans(mymat2, k=i)$quality))
  # this loop errors out after k=6 for me but the answer is already clear.
}

ggplot(df2) + geom_line(aes(x=n_clust, y=quality))
```

[image: Example 2 Optimality Plot]

Once again the biggest increase in `quality` is from 2 clusters to 3 clusters.

Anyone have suggested alternatives?  This is taking a very long time to compute solutions on my actual dataset of over 2500 histograms.  Similarly, I would imagine that it might take far too long on other datasets that have histograms for multiple variables.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for such a helpful answer to this question several years down the road! I'm trying to test the stability of my clusters. I have 700 histograms, I was thinking of applying this method to 30% of the data, then applying that clustering scheme to the whole dataset, and then repeating that whole process two or three times to see if the clusters lead to the same classifications each time. But I can't figure out how to apply the clustering scheme to another set of data. Any ideas? If you need more clarification, or if this worth a separate question, let me know.

Comment: That's an excellent question! I suggest asking this as a separate question. My first instinct would be to use a `predict` method on the returned object (e.g., `fit = WH_kmeans(trainMatH, ...); predict(fit, testMatH);`. However, the package author has not implemented a predict method as far as I can tell.  I suggest submitting an issue on their github Issues page: https://github.com/Airpino/HistDAWass/issues